# Add custom javascript to application page

Tags: 2013, javascript, jslink

Is there any way to add JavaScript to a custom application page that is deployed to _layouts/CustomFunctionality/ without any server side deployment ?

I have a custom NewForm.aspx where I need to add a custom JSlink, however, the page is ghosted so I cannot
set this property or add a custom JS from interface...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Application pages (standard or custom) are .aspx pages "hard-deployed" on the SharePoint servers. There's only one physical copy (on the disk, it's in the file system "hive" of SharePoint) on every server of the farm. There's no DB-copy of them.
If you cannot access the server, there's no physical option to customize the page.